# Is there anything interesting about taking the logarithm of the determinant?

Tags: group-theory, determinant

We can view the determinant as a group homomorphism
$$\det : GL_n(F) \to F^\times$$
since $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. If the field is the real numbers, we can take the logarithm of the determinant, which by definition maps $\mathbb{R}^\times$ to $\mathbb{R}$ under addition. So then the composition $\log\circ\det$ can be seen as taking the group of $n \times n$ matrices with positive determinant to the group of real numbers under addition.

Is there anything interesting about this map, or is there nothing else to say other than it is just the "logarithm of the dterminant"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde because $\exp \circ \det$ does not map the multiplicative part of the field to the additive part. I was wondering if this was interesting since it is a group map from $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$ under addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trace of the Lie algebra? Since the determinant is the volume ratio under the linear map, its logarithm is the growth rate indicated by the trace of the corresponding Lie algebra element.

Comment: In other words, $\det\exp A=\exp{\rm tr}A$ (converting to exponential form).